# How do you show results of table A then results of table B?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to show all results of table A then all results of table B.

I tried to make 2 SELECTs in my query but it didn't work.

I'm not making 2 different queries because I want to paginate it together.

EDIT: I have a 'folders' table and a 'files' table.
I want to display all folders then all files.

Comment: `SELECT <query a> UNION ALL SELECT <query b>` may be what you're looking for, however it's a bit hard to tell from the somewhat basic info you're giving.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I've already tryed this, but it don't works because my tables have different columns

Comment: why don't you use joins

Comment: @RahulSingh because I don't know if its possible to join two tables then order the result by tables ...

Comment: If the two queries have different columns, how are you looking to combine them at all?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I just want to have the results of SELECT * FROM folders then the results of SELECT * FROM files

Comment: I finally found the answer by myself!

Just by adding empty columns to a column so they finally have the same amount of columns ! :) thank you all !

Select *, Null as Col8, Null as Col9 from folders
Union
Select * from files

Comment: You do realize people here been telling you that both of tables has to have exact amount of columns in order to use UNION?

Comment: @Veljko89 yes sorry but I did not realise they were talking about the amount now that's fine thank again

Comment: When you say 'paginate together' I assume you are using a data control on a form or a report. You should use 2 controls, on following the other, each control grabbing up one table of data. SQL isn't the tool to use for paginating two disparate datasets -- that's a job to be done at the View step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your columns are different, you need two queries instead of one, that is the simplest solution.

If you really want to combine, you can try this:

```
SELECT 'A' as source, col_1a, col_2a, col_3a, NULL as col_1b, NULL as col_2b, NULL as col_3b FROM table_a
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', NULL, NULL, NULL, col_1b, col_2b, col_3b FROM table_b
ORDER BY source, col_1a, col_1b
```

The result is like this:

```
source, col_1a, col_2a, col_3a, col_1b, col_2b, col_3b
'A',    1,      'a',    'aa',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL
'A',    2,      'a',    'aa',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL
'B',    NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   1,      'b',    'bb'
'B',    NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   2,      'b',    'bb'
'B',    NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   3,      'b',    'bb'
```

Comment: Although this works in practice, a SQL query is not guaranteed to return results in a particular order unless you have an `order by` clause.  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets, unless there is an explicit `order by`.